# Check if custom TableViewCell is nil

Tags: ios, swift

I have two prototype cells `BasicCell` and `BasicCell2`. Both have a label `titlet` in it. I am unable to check for nil cel

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if(indexPath.row == 0 && flagcheck == 0 ) {
        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BasicCell2") as BasicCell2
        if cell2 == nil {
            cell2 = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "BasicCell2")
        }

        cell2.titlet.text = question+"\n"+"\n"
        cell2.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor("b2cecf")
        cell2.userInteractionEnabled = false
        return cell2

    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 0){
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BasicCell") as BasicCell
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "BasicCell")
        }

        cell.titlet.text = question+"\n"+"\n"
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BasicCell") as BasicCell
        if cell === nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "BasicCell")
        }
        cell.titlet.text = self.data1[indexPath.row-1]
        return cell
    }
}
```

This is the error which I get

```
 Cannot invoke '==' with an argument list of type '(BasicCell, NilLiteralConvertible)'
```

This is my BasicCell.swift

```
  import UIKit

  class BasicCell: UITableViewCell {
  @IBOutlet weak var titlet: UILabel!
  }
```

Comment: if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BasicCell") as BasicCell {
   
} else {
   
}

Comment: If you're making the cells in a storyboard, and you pass the correct identifier, the cell will never be nil, so there's no reason to check.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to unwrap the cell before performing the comparison operation.

```
let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BasicCell2") as BasicCell2! 
        if cell2 == nil {
            cell2 = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "BasicCell2")
        }
```

Check the BasicCell! (The "!" character is unwrapping character).

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Cannot assign let value to cell in the last line of code